# Powermail: fill empty fields with a default value

Tags: forms, typo3, powermail

I am trying to create a contact form in which users can fill out optional fields. I set `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.showOnlyFilledValues = 0` so that empty fields are still shown on the confirmation page (right before submitting the form) and in the email as well.
So far so good, but in this case, I would like to give them some sort of default value.
So it's not like `Name: _______` but more like `Name: empty`. How would I do that?

TYPO3 7.6, Powermail 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the values on the confirmation page with TypoScript (see https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt#L606 for a small example).
With some lines of TypoScript you will get it to work :)